# chartjs y axis start from 0 if all values is zeros

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

i am using react-chartjs-2 v4.1.0 and chart.js v3.9.1

and i have this issue here

[image: line chart image]

**how to force chartjs to start from 0 on y-axis?**

*(some additional info here)*

my line chart options:
[image]

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#axis-range-settings. Also check syntax of V2  vs V3: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html#scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `min: 0` in the root of the y axis options object instead of it being nested inside of the `ticks` options